# Custom permalinks working in http but not in https wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, https

Hi there my web site is working fine for http with postname option in Permalink .Recently i activate https (i.e ssl) for my website after that only home page is working, sub pages are not working.For default Permalink settings https is working

I checked http.conf file ..

```
my port is 443 it is free also.and also i have installed WordPress HTTPS plugin also
```

check my site links

https://qa.xprshealth.com/  //working

https://qa.xprshealth.com/?dwqa-question=how-can-i-register-as-doctor   //working
    https://qa.xprshealth.com/community/  //not working

help me to solve this problem .thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

most of the time you have to set domain level +subdomain or pages in SSL.

check in your ssl settings like what directories are SSL enabled.... it must be simple